# Aren't bash script variable untyped (converted automatically)?

Tags: bash

```
touch "data"
if [ $(stat -c%s "data") < 1024 ]; then
    echo "not this file"
fi
```

It cannot check whether the file size is less than 1MiB. (Of course, `data` should be an empty file.)

It would give this error:

```
./chk.sh: line 2: 1024: No such file or directory
```

Aren't bash script variable untyped (converted automatically)?

Comment: In BASH you can also do `(( $(stat -c%s "f1") < 1024 )) && echo "not this file"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `-lt` instead of `<` for integer comparison

`=` and `!=` are used for string comparisons

`<` and `>` are used for redirection

Comment: In bash, you can use `<` and `>` for string comparison, but you have to quote them. (Inside [[ ]], you don't need to quote them.)

Comment: Or you can use `(( ))`, in which case `<` and `>` do numeric comparison (and don't need to be quoted). No, this syntax is not at all consistent or intuitive. See [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for more options & examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you enclose your condition around `((` and `))` you can use the `<` operator:

```
touch "data"
if (( $(stat -c%s "data") < 1024 )); then
   echo "not this file"
fi
```

The `(( <EXPRESSION> ))` is called [Arithmetic evaluation](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/arithmetic_eval) and works only with with [Arithmetic expressions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr).

**Update:** As pointed by [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici), the `<` operator enclosed between `[[` and `]]` will do String comparison,   something like `[[ 3 < 21 ]]` will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: It looks better than -lt.

Comment: < is string comparison, not numeric comparison. So it will give unexpected results.

Comment: @rici it is a numeric comparison in `let`(the double parens).

Comment: @jrd: when i wrote that comment, the answer used [[